# Apply CSS to active dropped element in a drop area using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have few draggable nodes which need to be highlighted after drop, only the element which is dropped needs to have a border.
Eg: I drop nodeA and it will be highlighted. Later when I drop nodeB, then nodeB should be highlighted and nodeA should not be highlighted.

This is the function I have written:

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
    test++;
    nodeCopy.id =test; /* We cannot use the same ID */
    var newNodeId= nodeCopy.id;
    ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
    document.getElementById(newNodeId).className += " draggeddStyle";
}
```

I am able to highlight the node using:

```
document.getElementById(newNodeId).className += " draggeddStyle;
```

After that, if I drag another node, both nodes end up having the same style.

Comment: what have you tried, where is your highlighting code ?

Comment: am able to highlight the node using 'document.getElementById(newNodeId).className += " draggeddStyle;'
this code..after that if i drag another node both nodes are having the styles

Comment: then you need to remove the style from the current node when you drag the second node

Comment: am not able to achieve it as i new to this.. so need help :)

Comment: Try removing classname first for existing elements in the beginning of this method.

$(".draggeddStyle").removeClass("draggeddStyle");

This should be very first line of the method in your code. Hope that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modifying your code sample.

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $(".draggeddStyle").removeClass("draggeddStyle");/* added this line */
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
    test++;
    nodeCopy.id =test; /* We cannot use the same ID */
    var newNodeId= nodeCopy.id;
    ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
    document.getElementById(newNodeId).className += " draggeddStyle";
}
```

I think this works.